# Python - Scrape Data from Table using BeautifulSoup4: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Python newbie here.

I am practicing and trying to scrape some data off a table using BeautifulSoup4 and then transfer it to an Excel sheet.
Been at it for a few hours and finally kicking in and asking for some help.

I keep getting the error:

*'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, openpyxl

# Scrape data from inmotion.dhl

try:
    url = requests.get('https://inmotion.dhl/en/formula-1/fastest-pit-stop-award')
    url.raise_for_status()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text,'html.parser')

    table = soup.find("table", class_="f1-award-table")
    table_body = table.find('tbody')

    rows = table_body.find_all('tr')

    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all('td')
        print(cols)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is raised at `table = soup.find...`, but the problem is actually that the site is blocking `requests.get` to protect itself, so your code hasn't scraped or even accessed the site at all.

It works with [selenium](https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/selenium-python/) for me (possibly because it's a bit better at mimicking human behavior.)

```
#from selenium import webdriver

def linkSoup(l):  
    # I downloaded and saved 'chromedriver.exe' to the same folder as this .py file
    driverD = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
    driverD.get(l)
    lSoup = BeautifulSoup(driverD.page_source, 'html.parser')
    driverD.close()
    del driverD
    return lSoup 


soup = linkSoup('https://inmotion.dhl/en/formula-1/fastest-pit-stop-award')

table = soup.find("table", class_="f1-award-table")
table_body = table.find('tbody')

rows = table_body.find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    print(cols)
```

The results look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ga0kY.png).

Comment: I appreciate the response. I had a feeling it had something to do with security and me not being able to access it. I'm super new to Python and API's in general so this is exciting stuff. Other than that issue, it seems like my logic/code was correct I believe? I just needed to find a way to bypass the block.

Comment: @LawrenceTN yes, the bs4 parts are fine, you just have to gain access first